# How to make my app notification listed in windows 10 notification list?

Tags: c#, winforms, notifications

I use below code to show notification in my Winform application. It shown but it dos't listed in notification list.

```
var notification = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon()
{
    Visible = true,
    Icon = System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Information,
    BalloonTipText = "Notification ..."
};
notification.ShowBalloonTip(5000);
Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the problem. I disposed notification before it listed.

Comment: Hi @N.M can you please share how to listed the notification in the windows

Comment: Hi @HarishKumar. I used code thad shown in the question but I think it is not proper way to do this you should keep looking.